# Calling an asmx service from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asmx

Need to call asmx service from one of my get methods in web api .How can we do that ? Can we add a config entry in appsettings to the asmx service url and call it from the web api get mehod?

web config app settings entry:

```
key="myOldWebservice" value = "http://testAPI/webservice/client.asmx"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the asmx service as a `Service Reference` to your project in VS and call asmx methods from that reference. Just like invoking methods in dlls.

Comment: Thank you .My bad, I was overthinking. Couldn't think of that simplest possibility. will try with that.